# TelephonyManager returns null for IMEI number: what can cause this?

Tags: android, telephonymanager, imei

I'm working on an Android app and am getting `null` back for the IMEI number when using `TelophonyManager`. This is happening on several Huawei phones. (All of them are Ascend Y530s).

The phones all have sim cards and otherwise seem to be operating normally. I was under the impression that only a broken phone would return `null` IMEI. Clearly this is not the case..

Questions. What exactly is this IMEI number - i.e where is it stored on the device? And what does it mean when a seemingly fine phone returns its value as `null`?

**EDIT**

I should mention that the IMEI number is not always `null`. About half the time it seems to be valid (though this is very difficult to measure since we have 5 phones returning null IMEI numbers \ *sometimes* )

Comment: could you please try dialling *#06#, and confirm whether the phone got a valid [IMEI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Mobile_Station_Equipment_Identity) number?

Comment: These phones have been deployed remotely so I can't access them. As far as I have understood, our clients have never had a problem getting the IMEI number using *#06#?

Comment: please contact the client request them to confirm it for you

Comment: I will ask. They have provided me IMEI numbers at least 4 times and have never mentioned seeing null - these are the phones that are returning null for an IMEI number. I should mention that this doesn't happen all the time (I'd say about half the time). We have a survey application, each survey should send through an IMEI number, and without it they are anonymous which is not useful to us

Comment: Ok, got it, for your need i can give you an answer which helps you :)

Comment: Do you have a reason for the imei number? We are using other identification methods at the moment...  But I'm worried that the phones are faulty

Comment: But yes. I've just confirmed that the code sometimes didn't work on those phones

Comment: Sometimes TelephonyManger.getDeviceId() will return null, please see the answer i've posted, and check if it helps you

Comment: I am Getting IMEI null on Android Q. is there any workaround for this?

Comment: I created a uuid, and stored that. Then if you get an IMEI as null 9 times out of 10 you can then associate the imei that you get once with that uuid. This allows you to clean up null imeis

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After your comment, to get unique device id for the survey app, i would suggest you to use [`Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID) as your unique id.

```
String   myAndroidDeviceId = Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Or you can use both as

```
public String getUniqueID(){    
    String myAndroidDeviceId = "";
    TelephonyManager mTelephony = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if (mTelephony.getDeviceId() != null){
        myAndroidDeviceId = mTelephony.getDeviceId(); 
    }else{
         myAndroidDeviceId = Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID); 
    }
    return myAndroidDeviceId;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will implement this tomorrow :)

Comment: Technically though, i'm interested to know what is the possible cause of this problem?

Comment: ok... gonna leave the question open in case someone knows. thanks for your help

Comment: is the for all phones?

Comment: Yes, for all phones @ZachSmith

Comment: Thanks we have implemented this fix and it achieves the desired result

Comment: I get a warning: **using getString to get device identifiers is not recommended**

Comment: Getting IMEI null on Android Q? Did anyone find out this too?

Comment: imei is restricted on Android 10 and up so that regular apps cannot get it: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#non-resettable-device-ids

Comment: is above solution will work for android 10 and above?