# Do all Devices have a IMEI number? If so, Can another Device Have the same one?

Tags: android, validation, sdk, mobile-devices, imei

I have three questions on what and how the IMEI can be used. My current knowledge is the IMEI is the devices "Social Security Number", [Source Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Mobile_Equipment_Identity), so:

1. Can another phone/device have the same IMEI?
2. If not, can I have my app use the IMEI to recognize that the device it is on is the exact same device it was used on before?
3. If this one is also a yes how could I get the Android SDK to pull the IMEI for device validation. (I'm looking for something like ANDROID_PULL_IMEI then Android_VALIDATECHECK_KEY or similar)

Answer (score 0):

CDMA devices have a MEID instead of an IMEI.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1972404/1953590) describes how to obtain them programmatically.

This is not foolproof.  I've encountered cheap Chinese devices where `TelephonyManager#getDeviceId()` returns `null` or some obviously bogus string like `"0123456789ABCDEF"`.

Comment: So what could be used to identify the device and only that device? so the app knows that it can continue to launch in to a password screen.

Comment: @Ken [This Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35157444/telephonymanager-returns-null-for-imei-number-what-can-cause-this) describes some workarounds.  I wouldn't worry about it too much.  Most devices will return a valid device ID.  Just be aware that a few don't.