# IMEI Getting null for the first time when we install application Android

Tags: android

I have tried different links but none of them works:

1. [TelephonyManager returns null for IMEI number: what can cause this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35157444/telephonymanager-returns-null-for-imei-number-what-can-cause-this)
2. [How to get device's IMEI/ESN number with code programming But in android > 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39385672/how-to-get-devices-imei-esn-number-with-code-programming-but-in-android-6)

and many more links but none of them working.

This is my **Utils Class**:

```
public static String getIMEINumber(Context context){
  TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
  return telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
}
```

Calling below code from my Activity:

```
String deviceIMEI = Utils.getIMEINumber(LoginActivity.this);
```

But this is giving me null sometimes (when we install App for the first time particularly).Can you help me on this?

Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

Comment: Can you guys Help me on this ?Please

Comment: Are you requirement add permisson and check request permission?

Comment: Added Permission and also checked requestPermission.Not working when we install application and when we run for first time

Comment: Can you please help me on this @Dungnbhut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See sample:

```
private int REQUEST_PERMISSION_PHONE_STATE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        showPhoneStatePermission();
    }


    private void showPhoneStatePermission() {
        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
        if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, REQUEST_PERMISSION_PHONE_STATE);
        } else {
            getIMEI();
        }
    }

    private void getIMEI() {
        String deviceId = IMEIUtil.getDeviceId(this);
        toastMessage(deviceId);
    }

    private void requestPermission(String permissionName, int permissionRequestCode) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{permissionName}, permissionRequestCode);
    }

    private void toastMessage(String msg) {
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSION_PHONE_STATE) {
            showPhoneStatePermission();
        }
    }
```

And class `IMEIUtil`:

```
public static String getDeviceId(Context context) {
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String deviceId = telephonyManager.getDeviceId().trim();
        if (deviceId == null) {
            String androidId = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
            deviceId = android.os.Build.SERIAL + "#" + androidId;
        }
        return deviceId.trim();
    }
```

Require add permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />` before tag `<application>` on AndroidManifest. You can see full code: https://github.com/HoangDang/GetIMEI/tree/master/GetIMEI. I hope it can help you!

Comment: Thanks for your Response @Dungnbhut.I cannot able to upvote because I dont have reputation.

Comment: If my answer can help you. You can tick"Owner Accepted". If not, I nice to help you!

Comment: Thanks for your help @Dungnbhut, Accepted.